# Angular 7 Unusual behavior When user navigate back to login he can access other components if he used the forward key of the browser

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am having a weird behavior with my angular application.

The app contain `Go Back` button, so the user can use it when needed:

```
goBack()
{
    this.location.back();
}
```

With `location` is an instance of `Location` imported form `@angular/common`.

When a user click on it and sent back to the login component, and on load of the `LoginComponent`, I clear all the credentials and enforce the user to login again.

The problem is that when the user go back into the login component, 2 scenarios are workable:

1. He can go forward by using the browsers arrow, and continue working and adding info normally;
2. The second scenario is if he went to login and get forward to the latest component, only if he refresh the page, my script will take effect and enforce him to login again.

What I need is the second one, and I want to terminate scenario 1.

The following script is the one I use inside the `login` component to clear credentials if a user navigated to login:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //If a uset gets back to login component, he should be logged out
    this.logout();
    this.globalVar.username = '';
    this.globalVar.jwt_token = '';
    this.globalVar.user_role = '';
    this.globalVar.user_id = '' ;
    this.globalVar.user_logged = false;
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');

}
```

`logout()` method:

```
logout() {
    this.authService.logoutService();
}
```

`logoutService()` method:

```
logoutService() {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    localStorage.removeItem('user_id');
    this.globalVar.user_logged = false;
    this.globalVar.user_id = '';
    this.globalVar.user_role = '';
    this.globalVar.username = '';
    this.globalVar.jwt_token = '';
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Only, and only if a user went back by mistake to login component and then went forward using the arrow of the browser, and he refresh the page, the previous scenario works.

What I need is to forbid the user from going to other component without loging in again.

Do I need to create a singleton wide app service, and use it in each component to check if the credentials are empty and `user_logged` is false, to navigate back to `login` ? Or is there another solution ? Or should I check the previous location, and if it is equal to login, I disable the go back button ?

Comment: You can use interceptors to prevent users from navigating back to pages before login.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: @Justcode it is like using a service and add it into all modules ?